# Concentrated Ozone Treatments for COVID-19 Sterilization: What levels and duration are safe for consumer electronics?

Tags: safety

Operating a critical IT service for necessary businesses brings some risks at this time that need to be mitigated. I have some powerful ozone equipment used to sanitize / sterilize rental property and am considering using this within some enclosures to facilitate safe drop-off and pickup zones of computers and various electronics for customers.

Are there any studies or solid experiences that demonstrate safe levels (and duration) of strong ozone exposure for consumer electronics?

I don't want to destroy any circuitry or even polymer seals for batteries, keyboards (rubber springs), etc. and thus want to make sure I research this option thoroughly before implementing this.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Ozone and electronic equipment](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/questions/144230/ozone-and-electronic-equipment)

Comment: Hmm, unfortunately it's not clear with regards to consumer electronics' rubber and plastic components as per this article that was referenced therein: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ozone_cracking - Note how we don't really have any solid information or data about common plastics that are traditionally used in consumer electronics, etc...